# How to use gnome_settings_daemon and volume_step?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, gnome-settings-daemon

http://www.blograndom.com/blog/2010/02/change-volume-key-step-size-in-ubuntu/

So, to change the effect the volume keys have:

Press Alt+F2 to bring up the “Run” box.
Type in “gconf-editor” and press enter.
Select “Apps > gnome_settings_daemon“
On the right hand side you’ll have a single option named “volume_step“
Change the numerical value (6 by default) to a lower one (3 seems pretty good)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesnt work in 11.10. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/871133